# format not being applied to data frame

Tags: r

I try to apply formatting to a data frame created from a printed TableOne object but it won't "stick"

Sample

```
library(dplyr)
library(tableone)
data(ovarian)
data <- ovarian
data$futime <- data$futime * 100 
vars <- c("futime","fustat")
catvars <- c("fustat")
table1 <- CreateTableOne(vars = vars, factorVars = catvars,strata = "rx", data = data)
print(table1, printToggle = F, quote = F)  %>%as.data.frame() %>% format(big.mark = ",")
```

Result:

```
                                     1                   2      p test
n                                   13                  13            
futime (mean (SD)) 51730.77 (34688.14) 68176.92 (32467.63)  0.224     
fustat = 1 (%)               7 (53.8)            5 (38.5)   0.694
```

This behaves similar to simply creating my own data frame

```
c(1213,2,3,1213,2,3) %>% table()%>% as.data.frame() %>% format(big.mark = ",")
```

Result:

```
     . Freq
1    2    2
2    3    2
3 1213    2
```

This is unlike when simply using the format option on a numeric variable or even a one column data frame

```
123321789 %>% format(big.mark = ",")
```

Result:

```
[1] "123,321,789"
```

```
or
c(1213,2,3,1213,2,3) %>% as.data.frame() %>% format(big.mark = ",")
```

Result:

```
1 1,213
2     2
3     3
4 1,213
5     2
6     3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so this one lead me down a rabbit hole of text formatting.

Ended up writing a function to address the matter, used address some weird rounding issues.

```
styleTableOne <- function(x){
  if(!is.na(as.numeric(x))){return(format(as.numeric(x),big.mark = ","))}
  if(x == ""){return(x)}
  if(x == "<0.001"){return(x)}
  if(x == "0.0"){return(x)}
  if(x == "    "){return(x)}
  if (length(strsplit(x, split = "(", fixed = T)[[1]]) == 2){
    set1 <- strsplit(x, split = "(",fixed = T)[[1]][1] %>% as.numeric()
    set2 <- strsplit(x, split = "(",fixed = T)[[1]][2] %>% str_remove(fixed(")")) %>% as.numeric()
    set1 <- case_when(
      set1 > 100 ~ round(set1,0),
      set1 > 25 ~ round(set1,1),
      T ~ round(set1,2)
    )
    set2 <- case_when(
      set1 > 100 ~ round(set2,0),
      set1 > 25 ~ round(set2,1),
      T ~ round(set2,2)
    )
    set1 %<>% format(big.mark = ",") 
    set2 %<>% format(big.mark = ",")
    set <- paste(set1,set2,sep = " (")
    set <- paste0(set,")")
    return(set)}
  x %>% strsplit(split = " ",fixed = T) %>% .[[1]] -> x
  x <- subset(x, x != "")
  set1 <- strsplit(x, split = " ",fixed = T)[1] %>% as.numeric()
  set2 <- strsplit(x, split = " ",fixed = T)[2] %>% str_remove(fixed("[")) %>% str_remove(fixed(",")) %>% as.numeric()
  set3 <- strsplit(x, split = " ",fixed = T)[3] %>% str_remove(fixed("]")) %>% as.numeric()
  set1 <- case_when(
    set1 > 100 ~ round(set1,0),
    set1 > 25 ~ round(set1,1),
    T ~ round(set1,2)
  )
  set2 <- case_when(
    set1 > 100 ~ round(set2,0),
    set1 > 25 ~ round(set2,1),
    T ~ round(set2,2)
  )
  set3 <- case_when(
    set1 > 100 ~ round(set3,0),
    set1 > 25 ~ round(set3,1),
    T ~ round(set3,2)
  )
  set1 %<>% format(big.mark = ",") 
  set2 %<>% format(big.mark = ",")
  set3 %<>% format(big.mark = ",")
  set <- paste0(set1," (",set2,"-",set3,")")
  return(set)
}
```

Then you can do:

```
library(survival)
library(dplyr)
library(tableone)
data(ovarian)
data <- ovarian
data$futime <- data$futime * 100 
vars <- c("futime","fustat")
catvars <- c("fustat")
table1 <- CreateTableOne(vars = vars, factorVars = catvars,strata = "rx", data = data)
print(table1, printToggle = F)  %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  sapply(sapply, styleTableOne) %>% 
  as.data.frame(row.names = row.names(print(table1)))
```

result:

```
                                 1               2     p test
n                               13              13           
futime (mean (SD)) 51,731 (34,688) 68,177 (32,468) 0.224     
fustat = 1 (%)            7 (53.8)        5 (38.5) 0.694
```